# CSS float is below Bootstrap nav bar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In my Rails 4 app, i'm having trouble getting the menu bars right. Specifically, these two divs overlap.

I want the block that says "Register" and "Log in" to be aligned with the menu on the left-hand side, except floating right. I don't want it to float slightly below the Bootstrap 3 nav div like this:

[image]

This looks especially unpleasant when someone signs in or out:

[image]

The side bar with "Register" or user name and "Log in" or "Log out" is in the class `nav pull-right`. In `bootstrap.css`, the relevant bit of code seems to be this:

```
.pull-right {
float: right !important;
}
```

Here is part of my `application.html.erb` code:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
<div class ="navbar-inner">
<div class="container">
<b><a href="#" class="brand">WHEELS Registration</a></b>
<ul class ="nav">
<%= link_to "All Events", events_path %>
</ul>
<ul class="nav pull-right">
    <% if user_signed_in? %>
    <li><%= link_to current_user.full_name, edit_user_registration_path %>  </li>
    <li><%= link_to "Log Out", logout_path %></li>
    <% else %>
      <li><%= link_to "Register", register_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Log in", login_path %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
<% flash.each do |type, message| %>
   <div class = "alert <%= flash_class type.to_s %> ">
  <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button> 
  <%= message %>
 </div>
<% end %>

<%= yield %>
</div>
```

The app is here if taking a look would help more: https://wheels-registration-yamilethmedina.c9.io/

(I haven't tagged this with Ruby on Rails because it's technically a CSS and bootstrap issue and I don't want to clog that tag,  but i'll add it if you consider it relevant)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add a `pull-left` class in a div containing the other part of the header. Something like that:

```
[...]
<div class="container">
    <div class="pull-left">
        <b><a href="#" class="brand">WHEELS Registration</a></b>
        <ul class ="nav">
        <%= link_to "All Events", events_path %>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav pull-right">
        [...]
```

Comment: I did this: `<div class="container pull-left">
      <b><a href="#" class="brand">WHEELS Registration</a></b>
      <ul class ="nav">
       <%= link_to "All Events", events_path %>
      </ul>`  and `.pull-left {
  float: left !important;
}` but it didn't seem to work

Comment: No, you need to add another div, not just add the pull-left to your container div. I edited my answer to clarify this.

Comment: Thanks, this is working great! The alert still overlaps slightly though. I tried to add a `margin-top` property but it doesn't make a difference. Here is the original code there: `.alert { padding: 15px; margin-bottom: 20px; border: 1px solid transparent; border-radius: 4px; }`

Comment: I'll suggest you to remove the class `.navbar-fixed-top` of your first div and  the `padding-top: 40px;` of the `body`. This will make your div's to use the space they really need. Then, if you want your title to be closer to the top navigation, decrease the `margin-bottom` of your top navbar and the `margin-top` of the `h1` element...

Comment: I don't have `padding-top: 40px` in `body`. The only place I see it is in `.col-xs-1, .col-sm-1, .col-md-1, .col-lg-1, .col-xs-2, .col-sm-2, .col-md-2, .col-lg-2, .col-xs-3, .col-sm-3, .col-md-3, .col-lg-3, .col-xs-4, .col-sm-4, .col-md-4, .col-lg-4, .col-xs-5, .col-sm-5, .col-md-5, .col-lg-5, .col-xs-6, .col-sm-6, .col-md-6, .col-lg-6, .col-xs-7, .col-sm-7, .col-md-7, .col-lg-7, .col-xs-8, .col-sm-8, .col-md-8, .col-lg-8, .col-xs-9, .col-sm-9, .col-md-9, .col-lg-9,` etc. (that label goes on for a long time)

Comment: Yes, you have. See it [here](https://wheels-registration-yamilethmedina.c9.io/assets/application.css?body=1).

Comment: oh man, I forgot about the separate `application.css` file! thanks! there may actually be a bit too much white space now, but at least none of the elements (including the alert) crowd out another one. great!